# Informix Group by Alias

Tags: sql, group-by, informix

What am I missing according to this query:

```
SELECT mymonth, Header1
FROM
(
SELECT month(startdatetime) as mymonth, (CASE WHEN MyTable.somecolumn =2 THEN count(somecolumn2) END) as Header1
FROM MyTable WHERE year(startdatetime)=2013
group by startdatetime 

) x
GROUP BY Header1
```

I've red somewhere that Informix is not supporting grouping by alias but when trying to set
GROUP BY 2, there is error too
Column Header1 must be in a Group by clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is very unusual.  The Informix server is confused about whether the CASE expression is an aggregate or not — and so am I.  As written, you would do best to rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT mymonth, Header1
  FROM (SELECT MONTH(startdatetime) AS mymonth,
               COUNT(somecolumn2)   AS Header1
          FROM MyTable
         WHERE YEAR(startdatetime) = 2013
           AND SomeColumn = 2
         GROUP BY startdatetime
       ) AS x
-- GROUP BY Header1;
;
```

There's no reason for the (commented out) outer-level GROUP BY clause that I can see.  Given the following test data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE MyTable
(
    startdatetime   DATE NOT NULL,
    somecolumn      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    somecolumn2     VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('2013-03-01', 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('2013-03-02', 2, 'Elephant');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('2013-03-03', 2, 'Rhinoceros');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('2013-03-04', 1, 'Elephant');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('2013-03-05', 3, 'Rhinoceros');
```

The output of the query is:

```
mymonth      header1
SMALLINT     DECIMAL(15,0)
     3               0
     3               1
     3               1
```

However, I suspect you've done some query minimization to illustrate the problem (if so, thank you), and in fact your main sub-query would have a few similar CASE expressions, not just one.  In that case, you should rewrite the CASE expression and aggregation along these lines:

```
SELECT mymonth, Header1
  FROM (SELECT MONTH(startdatetime) AS mymonth,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN MyTable.somecolumn = 2 THEN somecolumn2 END) AS Header1
          FROM MyTable
         WHERE YEAR(startdatetime) = 2013
         GROUP BY mymonth 
       ) AS x
;
```

For the same sample data, this produces:

```
mymonth     header1
SMALLINT    DECIMAL(15,0)
     3               2
```

Given that you are using IBM Informix 11.50 instead of 11.70 or 12.10, you may have to use a variation on this to get the aggregation done:

```
SELECT MonthNum, COUNT(Header1) AS Header1
  FROM (SELECT MONTH(startdatetime) AS MonthNum,
               CASE WHEN MyTable.somecolumn = 2 THEN somecolumn2 END AS Header1
          FROM MyTable
         WHERE YEAR(startdatetime) = 2013
       ) x
 GROUP BY MonthNum;
```

Output:

```
monthnum    header1
SMALLINT    DECIMAL(15,0)
     3               2
```

The basic idea is to use the CASE expression to generate the values you want in the Header1 column of the sub-query, and then apply the aggregates to the results of the sub-query (instead of aggregating in the sub-query).  I've not verified that this will work in 11.50 (it does in 11.70.FC6), but there's a decent chance that it will.

Comment: last query is exactly what I'm looking for, but there is a big problem
I have Informix 11.50 Version and as far as I  see it does not support case statements inside count function am I wrong ? if so is there any workaround. And thank you for help :)

Comment: Always state your version numbers — rules change.  I tested with IBM Informix 11.70.  As of 2013-03-26, IBM Informix 12.10 is the current version.  By far the simplest solution is to upgrade; the later versions have a number of improvements like this in the core SQL language.  I'll mull over some alternatives in an update to the answer.

Comment: As always, Jon's answer is detailed and instructive. I've also updated my answer, with a variation on how to do multiple counts in one go. We have 11.5 at $work, in process of migrating to 11.7, and I know that approach works fine.

Comment: approach with applying the aggregates to the results works like a charm. so hardcore
:)

Answer (score 3):

That's some very peculiar syntax you've got in that query. I think it's the `CASE` statement that's causing the issue.

What is that achieving that isn't handled in this much simpler version?

```
SELECT MONTH(startdatetime) AS mymonth, COUNT(*) AS header1
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE YEAR(startdatetime) = 2013
    AND somecolumn = 2
GROUP BY 1
```

If you're trying to do something more funky than what you've put in your sample with that `CASE` statement, then I'd recommend trying something like this:

```
SELECT ...., SUM(DECODE(somecolumn, 2, 1, 0))
```

... but usually that style of syntax gets used when you're doing multiple `SUM()s` with varying predicates.

---

*UPDATE*

Where there are multiple predicates for counting, I like to do it this way:

```
SELECT ....
    SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col3 = 7 AND col5 = 0 THEN 1
             WHEN col3 = 5 AND col5 = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END) AS count2
  FROM ....
```

That gives you a lot of flexibility to count a lot of different things in 1 SQL statement, as long as they're being `GROUP`ed the same way.

Comment: Reason I'm not using condition (somecolumn=2) inside WHERE clause is, that there is more columns that have to be calculated and they have different values from number 2

Comment: That's the point of my final note there, using the `DECODE()` approach. See my updated answer