# GROUP BY in Informix (11.5)

Tags: sql, informix

Following Example Table Structure:

```
NR1 | NR2 | PRENAME | LASTNAME
```

If i query all 4 fields of this table and grouping it´s first 2 fields (`NR1,NR2`) in mysql,
i can do something like this:

```
SELECT NR1,NR2,PRENAME,LASTNAME FROM tbl GROUP BY NR1,NR1
```

But this won´t work in informix.

```
INFORMIX ERROR: the column (PRENAME) must be in the group by list
```

After reading some Topics at google, it is an "Informix feature" that all Selected Columns has to be in the Grouping List.
But if i will do that, the result is not that result, that i wish to have.
If i use

```
DISTINCT
```

instead `GROUP BY` the result is similar false, because i can not put the `DISTINCT`function only to column 1 and 2.

So: How can i make a "MYSQL GROUP BY" function ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699456/informix-group-by-alias

Comment: Well, your `group by` in MySQL was wrong to begin with.

Comment: @AvinashBabu answer looks nice, but how can i select more than one column. if i enhance the first SQL (from the Post)  -> GROUP BY + MISSING Column Error. If i add it to the SubSelect (After "FROM") Nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original syntax is suitable in one database -- MySQL.  And, that database says that the results of the non-aggregated columns come from *indeterminate* rows.  So, an equivalent query is just to use `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
SELECT NR1, NR2, MIN(PRENAME), MIN(LASTNAME)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY NR1, NR1;
```

My guess is that you want an arbitrary value from just one row.  I'd be inclined to concatenate them:

```
SELECT NR1, NR2, MIN(PRENAME || ' ' || LASTNAME)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY NR1, NR1;
```